# Update table cell on notification

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

How can I update a tabelview cell when a particular notification received, without reloading table data. notification tells the id of the cell that I need to update. So I want to iterate all table cells and update only the relevant table cell without reloading it. how can i do this

Comment: You don't want to just repopulate the table?  Have you tried to just iterate?  I think that is a bad solution, personally.

Comment: What is the difference between "Reloading" and "Updating" the cell ?

Comment: @Julien reloading will reload all the table cells. which is annoying. Update only one tablecell is the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[tableView visibleCells]` to get a list of all cells that are displayed. Iterate through this array to see if the cell you need to update is displayed, then do whatever you need to. (this method is if you're reusing cells).

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the built in `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` instead of trying to usurp the framework's functions. This will efficiently only reload the cell you ask it two not the entire table or even an entire section.

> Reloads the specified rows using a certain animation effect.
>
> Reloading a row causes the table view to ask its data source for a new cell for that row. The table animates that new cell in as it
>   animates the old row out. Call this method if you want to alert the
>   user that the value of a cell is changing. If, however, notifying the
>   user is not important—that is, you just want to change the value that
>   a cell is displaying—you can get the cell for a particular row and set
>   its new value.
>
> When this method is called in an animation block defined by the beginUpdates and endUpdates methods, it behaves similarly to
>   deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:. The indexes that UITableView
>   passes to the method are specified in the state of the table view
>   prior to any updates. This happens regardless of ordering of the
>   insertion, deletion, and reloading method calls within the animation
>   block.
>
> Available in iOS 3.0 and later.